# git push a commit that doesn't belong to any branch

Tags: git

I have got a commit-id, currently it doesn't belong to any of the branch. It has got a label. How do I push this commit to server?

```
git show 2.0.rc10
tag 2.0.rc10
Tagger: ....
Date:   Fri Mar 29 13:38:55 2013 -0700
Release 2.0.rc10;  merged 
commit f1186bfeb938081f9d57f8ac20667329b1c53111
```

while running

```
git branch -r --contains f1186bfeb938081f9d57f8ac20667329b1c53111
```

there is no output.

How to push this commit to server?

```
git push origin 2.0.rc10
remote: Tag '2.0.rc10' references unknown objects. Push commits before tags.
To 
 ! [remote rejected] 2.0.rc10 -> 2.0.rc10 (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'remote'
```

Comment: It looks like you have a pre-receive hook on the server that is rejecting.

Comment: Whence is the single commit you describe above?  Was it deleted at some point from a branch?

Comment: @merlin2011, yes, pre-receive hook is rejecting, the question is "how can i push such commit ids to server?" so that I can push tag later

Comment: @Tim Biegeleisen, yes, may be the branch was deleted. Since its has a tag, I want to preserve both commit-id and tag on server.

Comment: @VonC Please review this question and the answers and let us know your opinion.

Comment: @b4hand: Can't you just remove/fix the pre-receive hook?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is not Git,  but a pre-receive hook on the server that apparently checks that the commit is referenced by a branch.

Obviously, a solution is to push your branch first. I'm not sure why you would want a tag without a branch.

Comment: The empty output from `git branch -r --contains` clearly shows that this commit has no branch.

Answer (score 1):

The commit in question needs to belong to a branch in order for you to commit it to the remote repository.  Assuming that the branch where you want the commit to be is called `yourbranch` then the following should do the trick:

```
git checkout yourbranch      # checkout the desired branch
git merge f1186bfe           # merge in the single commit
git push origin yourbranch   # push the branch out (with new commit) to the remote
```

There may be merge conflicts which you will have to resolve.  And you should establish that you really want this commit.  You can inspect it using:

```
git show f1186bfe
```

You can make sure that the tag you want is still on the commit:

```
git show 2.0.rc10
```

Verify that the SHA-1 hash matches the commit you want to save, then push out the tag to the remote via this:

```
git push origin 2.0.rc10
```

Comment: is it necessary that all commits to be pushed onto server belong to a branch. What if (above case) they have only tag associated (but not branch)? I have several such tags in the code I am importing, is there a way "git push --tags" can exclude all such tags at-least?

Comment: AFAIK you cannot push a commit which has no associated branch.  By default, Git tags will not be pushed out with commits, so you don't need to do anything special to exclude tags, just don't push them.

Comment: No, it’s not necessary that all commits are reachable from a branch. Reachable from a tag is also good. You can push all tags using `git push --tags`, yes; not only those that are on a branch, but all of them.

Comment: as the [git-scm page](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Tagging#Sharing-Tags) says, it's not necessary for all commits to be reachable: `You will have to explicitly push tags to a shared server after you have created them. This process is just like sharing remote branches – you can run git push origin [tagname]`

Comment: @vguzmanp The primary question the OP is asking is how to push a local commit which has no branch to the server, _not_ the issue about the tag.

Comment: yes, but your first statement is `The commit in question needs to belong to a branch in order for you to commit it to the remote repository.`, which is plain wrong, as the OP says that the commit has a tag.

Comment: OK...please enlighten me by replying with the exact Git command you use to push a single commit to a remote repository which has no branch.

Comment: Sorry, edited my comment as you were replying. As the OP says that the commit has a tag, a simple `git push origin [tagname]` would do.

Comment: I don't see any mention of the *pre-receive hook* and thus I'm afraid this answer totally misses the point. Also it seems to make false claims about what Git allows and fails to show the easiest way to push a tagged commit.

Answer (score 0):

```
git push origin 2.0.rc10
```

Is effectively the command to push your commit. As the commit is referenced by the tag `2.0.rc10`, it is being pushed without problem.

Your error comes when the remote, **before** using what you sent, rejects it (`pre-receive hook declined`).You will need to modify your pre-receive hook or push something that your hook accepts. [More info about hooks](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks)

**Some tests**

Recreating OP's situation:

```
git checkout --orphan orphan_branch
git commit -am "stray commit"
git tag -a 2.0.rc10 -m "2.0.rc10"
git checkout master
git branch -D orphan_branch
```

Stray commit:

```
git show 2.0.rc10
tag 2.0.rc10
Tagger: ...
Date:   Fri Jun 5 11:41:11 2015 +0200

2.0.rc10

commit 78e06b3a4841f88c1737ab8986fd6f3d753e1735
Author: ...
Date:   Fri Jun 5 11:41:00 2015 +0200

    stray commit
```

[image: showing the stray commit]

Push:

```
git push origin 2.0.rc10
Username for ...
Password for ...
Counting objects: 2, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (2/2), done.
Writing objects: 100% (2/2), 305 bytes | 0 bytes/s, done.
Total 2 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0)
To ...
 * [new tag]         2.0.rc10 -> 2.0.rc10
```

So the commit is pushed and the tag created in the remote, as I don't have a pre-receive hook, it's pushed without a problem.

Comment: This won't get the stray commit into the remote repository.

Answer (score 0):

If you can see the commit on github, create a patch (adding .patch in url) and apply it.

Comment: This gave me a 404.